# App Crashing With Proguard Enabled

Tags: java, android, eclipse, obfuscation, proguard

My app runs perfectly without proguard enabled but when I enable it the app crashes right away. I have tried many combinations in the configuration to no avail.

Is there something that I should be keeping that I'm missing?

proguard config: https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/99fc07807950bae8e4f5

Unobfuscated log: https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/6cba7fc941a79d85802f

onSuccess(): https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/e7a4916c42d3ca065c99

Comment: Can you turn off obfuscation but leave the other options (optimizations, method stripping) enabled?  If it still fails you'll be able to see exactly where it's breaking.

Comment: @fadden Good idea. How would I do that?

Comment: Can you track down which line in `onSuccess()` throws the NPE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the offending code. I changed my Proguard.cfg to match the following:

https://github.com/google/gson/blob/9f8ace9ac4c56b82eba1bbd8b44f80e042bda7e0/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

And now everything is working!

Comment: seems like link is broken, getting "SVN hosting has been permanently disabled"

Comment: Yeah, it would be really cool if you'd just attach the code you used.

Comment: I don't know which revision, but the file is at https://github.com/google/gson/commits/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Answer (score 3):

Usually proguard removes few classes if they are not explicitly set as

```
-keepclassmembers ....
```

But such errors are shown as `classNotFound`, `NoSuchMethodException` etc..,

Anyways decode the log cat you got using 
[this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding) and check what actually caused the **NPE**.

Comment: Great stuff! Ok i updated my answer with the unobfuscated dump.