# AdMob making my app crash in release version

Tags: android, admob

i just added AdMob to my app. Everything seem to work well when i debug or install release version of app (HTC m7). The problem occurs on CHUWI VX2 device (esky82_tb_cn_kk, Android 4.4). It is very strange because on this device my App works in debug mode but doesn't works in release version. I try turn of pro-gourd but it doesn't help me.

Any one have idea for that?

my manifest

instruction inside my onCreate method:

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed();
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                super.onAdOpened();
                mAdView.startAnimation(fade_in);
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                mAdView.startAnimation(fade_in);
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                super.onAdLeftApplication();
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

code inside layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >        

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView  android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Crash log:

```
05-01 19:39:16.305      124-124/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ Skip composition for [Built-in Screen (type:0)] since dirtyRegion is empty
05-01 19:39:16.321      124-124/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ Skip composition for [Built-in Screen (type:0)] since dirtyRegion is empty
05-01 19:39:16.330    2162-2162/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-01 19:39:16.330    2162-2162/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d79c98)
05-01 19:39:16.330    2162-2162/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
05-01 19:39:16.331    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{freshfrog.pytomat/freshfrog.pytomat.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 19:39:16.332    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
05-01 19:39:16.332    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
05-01 19:39:16.332    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-01 19:39:16.332    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
05-01 19:39:16.332    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
05-01 19:39:16.332    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-01 19:39:16.333    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
05-01 19:39:16.333    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 19:39:16.333    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-01 19:39:16.333    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
05-01 19:39:16.333    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
05-01 19:39:16.333    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 19:39:16.334    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 19:39:16.334    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at freshfrog.pytomat.Main.onCreate(Main.java:450)
05-01 19:39:16.334    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
05-01 19:39:16.334    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
05-01 19:39:16.334    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
05-01 19:39:16.335    2162-2162/? W/System.err﹕ ... 11 more
05-01 19:39:16.335    2162-2162/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
05-01 19:39:16.336      124-124/? I/SurfaceFlinger﹕ Skip composition for [Built-in Screen (type:0)] since dirtyRegion is empty
05-01 19:39:16.339    2162-2162/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: freshfrog.pytomat, PID: 2162
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{freshfrog.pytomat/freshfrog.pytomat.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at freshfrog.pytomat.Main.onCreate(Main.java:450)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 19:39:16.341      654-669/? V/Provider/Settings﹕ from settings cache , name = dropbox:data_app_crash , value = null
05-01 19:39:16.342      654-669/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=128KB
05-01 19:39:16.342      654-669/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
05-01 19:39:16.343      654-669/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
05-01 19:39:16.343      654-669/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
05-01 19:39:16.343     916-2188/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=128KB
05-01 19:39:16.343     916-2188/? D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
05-01 19:39:16.343     916-2188/? D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
05-01 19:39:16.343     916-2188/? D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
05-01 19:39:16.343     654-2191/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=82: interp stack at 0x64403000
05-01 19:39:16.343     654-2191/? D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=82: created from interp
05-01 19:39:16.343      654-669/? D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
05-01 19:39:16.343      654-669/? V/Provider/Settings﹕ from settings cache , name = send_action_app_error , value = 1
05-01 19:39:16.343      654-669/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity freshfrog.pytomat/.Main
```

Logcat indicate this line (Main.java:450)

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
```

Comment: can you please highlight line 450?

Comment: Yes. this is line 450: mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. This issue isn't connect with AdView. It was problem with project. I made small mistakes. I don't have this line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

on the start of xml layout file. I don't know how it can event works.

1. I reboot device
2. I added missing line to xml
3. I clean project (Build > Clean Project)
4. I rebuild project (Build > Rebuild Project)

Then my apk starts work without progourd but crash when I enable this feature. So i find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243550/app-crashing-with-proguard-enabled)

5. I configure progourd configuration file [like this](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg?r=878).

Answer (score 2):

what is this ?

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

what were you expecting? to hit both sides?

try this

```
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

and let the rest go

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException on line 450 of `Main`.
Look at that line. Something there has not been initialised.